# IOS Core Data Fetch LAST object from Entity?

Tags: ios, core-data, fetch

I'm not finding a reference to "Last" so I'll ask what I hope is a fairly simple need to fulfill.  I have objects in a core data entity.  Currently I do not implement any sort of "time stamp" on this entity which would not help much anyway because the users travel coast to coast but I suppose I could always stamp in zulu time.

I need to retrieve the LAST object that was added to refer to an attribute's value.  I know core data stores it's own unique incrementing "key" but I don't know how to reference it.  I need to check to see if the odometer reading the user is trying to enter is less then the last one entered or varies beyond normal bounds to check for user input error before saving a new object and present an alertview if so.

I can't look for @MAX because the user may have made an erroneous high entry prior. but I can deal with that issue separately once the user has determined he has made an invalid entry somewhere that needs to be addressed and dealt with accordingly.

Thanks.

Comment: An interesting suggestion from Jemery Fox: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508128/how-do-i-get-the-last-record-of-a-core-data-database

Comment: OK, I had hoped there was some sort of built in method to get the last object but the discussion you pointed me to was my plan B.  I'll just insert a GMT timestamp (for consistency) to all new objects and sort on that and fetch the object at row 0